# Increase disk size by merging partitions

Tags: filesystems, partition, dual-boot, gparted

I'd like to have some more space on my Linux partition. My laptop is a Windows/Fedora dual boot. I have made a partition that I want to add to my Fedora partition. I can't figure out how to merge (or add, whatever the correct terminology is). You can see the situation below

[image: current file system status]

I have read that I have to delete the dev/sda5 part so that I can then merge the two others, but I can't delete that without also deleting dev/sda6, which would wipe everything and that is something I'd like to avoid.

I have little knowledge about this, so please make a clear answer without too much technical details. If you need more info, please ask and I will try to give it asap.

Comment: can you edit your post with result from both `pvs` and `vgdisplay -v` ? (it is likely you just have to create a new partition, then a new PV and add it to existing VG)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Archemar, you need to:

1. Create the partition. You can use the unallocated shown in your screenshot.
2. Create an LVM physical volume using the partition. Assuming the device is sda7: `pvcreate /dev/sda7`
3. Add the physical volume to your LVM volume group. We can't see the name of the volume group in your screenshot, but you can get it using `vgs`. Assuming it's called fedora: `vgextend fedora /dev/sda7`

The above steps will make the space provided by the new partition, available for use by any of your LVM logical volumes. You can list your logical volumes with `lvs` and resize them using `lvextend`. When using `lvextend` I recommend using the `-r` option so that the underlying filesystem is resized as well. Take a look at `man lvextend` for examples.